# Returning protocol type

Tags: swift

I have a protocol `GraphType` that can have specific implementations:

```
protocol GraphType {
    var vertexCount: Int {get}
    var edgeCount: Int {get}
    init(vertexCount: Int)
    ...
}
```

Then I have a function to construct an MST:

```
func primsMST(graph: GraphType) -> GraphType {
    let ret = graph.dynamicType(vertexCount: graph.vertexCount)

    return ret
}
```

There is no direct compiler warning in the code, but the compiler complains about the function:

1. While emitting IR SIL function @_TF10SwiftStuff8primsMSTFPS_9GraphType_PS0__ for 'primsMST' at /Users/aeubanks/Dropbox/Programming/Apps/SwiftStuff/SwiftStuff/MST.swift:9:1

   Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

This shouldn't be a problem right? The function takes in any object that implements `GraphType` and returns an arbitrary `GraphType` which happens to be the same as the input. When I replace `graph.dynamicType` with a specific implementation like `GraphAdjacencyList` without changing the return type it compiles, but I would prefer if the return type was the same class as the inputted graph. Auto-correct even says that `ret` is of `GraphType`. Any way to solve this?

Comment: The Swift people have made it pretty clear that code that compiles but then crashes the compiler is problematic and they want to know about it. So please file a bug report with Apple! Meanwhile, I've posted a workaround with a generic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a generic function. Here's a reduced version of your code:

```
protocol GraphType {
    var vertexCount: Int {get}
    init(vertexCount: Int)
}
func primsMST<T:GraphType>(what:T) -> GraphType {
    let result = T(vertexCount:what.vertexCount)
    return result
}
```

Let's try it out. I'll define a struct that adopts your GraphType:

```
struct St : GraphType {
    var vertexCount = 0
    init(vertexCount:Int) {
        self.vertexCount = vertexCount
    }
}
```

Here we go....

```
    let st = St(vertexCount:25)
    let result = primsMST(st)
```

A little logging / breakpointing will show that `result` is what you want it to be.

Comment: Actually, could declare the generic func `func primsMST<T:GraphType>(what:T) -> T` since the whole point is that what goes in is what comes out. :)

Comment: Oh duh that makes more sense than the roundabout way I did. Thanks!

Comment: I don't agree. I'd like to know what's wrong with what you were doing. The fact that it compiles suggests there's _nothing_ wrong with it. So you've just hit a bug, and all I've done is suggest a different way, not a better way.

Comment: Nevertheless, if my answer helped you, and if you were to accept it, I wouldn't object!